# Any known issues running embedded non-HA Neo4j 1.9 with Java 6?

Tags: neo4j

While I am fully aware of the fact that an upgrade to Java 7 should be done, till that time, are there any known issues using Neo4j 1.9 (RC1) with Java 6?
I am using it in embedded mode, non-HA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the exact same environment and haven't come across any problems. If you would be using SDN, you might just bump into some issues, but I guess they'll be solved soon. See e.g. [DATAGRAPH-338](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAGRAPH-338).